# Output text from command-prompt to a file without using pipes

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

How can I save text that is already present in a console screen to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

1. Switch to the command-prompt
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>K</kbd>
4. Use the mouse to drag a selection rectangle around the desired text
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Open Notepad (or other text editor)
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>) to paste
8. Save file

You can also select all of the text in the console window with <kbd>S</kbd> instead of <kbd>K</kbd> at step 2.

You can also right-click the console and select *Mark*.

---

You can simplify the whole process by enabling quick-edit mode (one time):

1. Switch to the command-prompt
2. Press <kbd>P</kbd>
3. Switch to the *Options* tab
4. Select *QuickEdit Mode*
5. Click `[OK]`

From now on, you can copy as needed:

1. Drag a selection rectangle
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy
3. Repeat step (1) as many times as needed

Comment: Can I not also right click the text to copy it?

Comment: Yup, that too. If you do it often, quick-edit mode is the fastest; if you do it infrequently, right-click is easiest (though you can just leave quick-edit mode on all the time if you don’t use any console programs that use the mouse).